# Detecting homotopy by precomposing with paths.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Let X and Y be topological spaces, and denote $\mathbb{S}^n$ the $n$-sphere.

i) Suppose that $f,g:X \to Y$ are maps such that for every path $\alpha: [0,1] \to X,$ we have that $f \circ \alpha$ is left homotopic to $g \circ \alpha$.
Does this imply that $f$ is left homotopic to $g$?

ii) Suppose instead that for every map $\alpha: \mathbb{S}^n \to X$ and every $n \geq 0, $ we have that $f \circ \alpha$ is left homotopic to $g \circ \alpha$. Is it true that $f$ and $g$ must be left homotopic?

iiia) If not, does this become true if we assume $X$ and $Y$ to be nice?

iiib) What if $X,Y$ are CW-complexes?

Note: these are not homework questions. They are questions which I am asking to myself but I don’t know how to answer because I don’t have time to think about them now.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: this is already a specific problem with enough detail to identify and adequate answer.

Comment: Please keep in mind one of our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), namely, [limit yourself to one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671). In fact, this is a guideline across all of stackexchange.

Comment: @LeeMosher it would have been completely pointless to ask a separate question for each subquestion, as they are all related, just in order to respect some bureaucratic guideline.

Comment: Nonetheless, I respectfully suggest that you view this not as a bureaucratic guideline (who would the bureaucrats even be on a site which is run by its own users?), but instead for what it is, namely a guideline designed to improve the body of questions on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that "left homotopic" just means "homotopic"?

**Q1:** No. $[0, 1]$ is contractible, so two maps from $[0, 1]$ to any other space are homotopic iff their image lies in the same path component. So if $Y$ is path-connected then every pair of maps $f, g : X \to Y$ satisfies this condition.

**Q2:** No. This condition is equivalent to requiring that $f$ and $g$ induce the same maps on homotopy groups $\pi_n(f), \pi_n(g) : \pi_n(X) \to \pi_n(Y)$ (if $X$ and $Y$ are disconnected, then we require this to hold at every basepoint), except that because of the lack of a basepoint, the condition on $\pi_1$ is that $f$ and $g$ induce the same maps on the set of conjugacy classes in $\pi_1$.

We can ask for the slightly stronger condition that $f$ and $g$ induce the same maps on each $\pi_n$, full stop, and also that $X$ and $Y$ are path connected to keep things simple with basepoints. This is "[Whitehead's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem) for maps" and even here the answer is still no: for example, $X$ and $Y$ can have nonzero homotopy groups in disjoint degrees, in which case every map induces the zero map between all homotopy groups, but there can still be more than one homotopy class of maps $X \to Y$.

My favorite counterexample here is to take $X = BG, Y = B^2 A$ to be [Eilenberg-MacLane spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space), where $G$ is a discrete group and $A$ is a discrete abelian group. $X$'s only nontrivial homotopy group is $\pi_1(X) = G$ and $Y$'s only nontrivial homotopy group is $\pi_2(Y) = A$ but the set of homotopy classes of maps between them can be identified with the second [group cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology) $H^2(G, A)$, which classifies [central extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Central_extension) of $G$ by $A$ and is already nontrivial for e.g. $G = A = C_2$.

This is a purely homotopy-theoretic phenomenon that persists even if $X$ and $Y$ are very nice in point-set terms; in particular $BG$ and $B^2 A$ can be taken to be CW complexes.

To get an example where $X$ and $Y$ are even manifolds we can take $X = T^2$ and $Y = S^2$. These again have nonzero homotopy groups in disjoint degrees: $X$'s only nonzero homotopy group is $\pi_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}^2$ whereas $Y$ is simply connected. But maps $X \to Y$ are classified up to homotopy by their degree (by the [Hopf degree theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_theorem)) and every degree occurs so there are countably many homotopy classes.

Comment: you just gave me the answer i was expecting, written in a very clear way. thank you very much!!!

Comment: i expect this to be false also if in question $ii)$ we use $ |\Delta^n|$ instead of $\mathbb{S}^n$, do you agree?

Comment: @lola: does $||$ mean geometric realization? Whatever it means I assume that's an $n$-simplex of some form, which is contractible so the same argument as in i) applies.

Comment: yes. thank you again